# Virtual keyboard can't interact with webpage via control event

Tags: javascript, html, uwp

I am using UWP JS to make a system application.

I have made one virtual keyboard, which works fine with the whole application.

I have also made one page that is used to open any website.

I can use my virtual keyboard with my application's textbox because I know the textbox's id.

However, I can't get the virtual keyboard to work with the website page because I don't know what the textbox id is.

Comment: Update your question with the code

Comment: When you initialise your virtual keyboard you should pass in the textbox id. Don't hardcode it in your application

Comment: Jasonscript thanks for reply, Actually I am new developer, I don't know what i do for open keyboard after click textbox.

Answer (score 0):

You could use tag selector to get all input element in your html page via jQuery. And call your visual keyboard in the `focus` event handle method.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("input").focus(function () {
         //Do some stuff
         $(this).addClass("bor");

     });
});
```